# I have a giant gap between the top and my right-floated div. What is causing this huge gap?

Tags: html, css-float

I have a float/clear problem of some sort on my right floated div. For some reason it has a ton of margin above it and will not "Dock" to the top like the left floated div. Was just wondering if an extra pair of eyes could see what I have been unable.

Tried many different combinations of float and clear to no avail.

```
#wrapper {
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#maincolumn {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
width: 774px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 3px solid purple;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#leftcolumn {
float: left;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
width: 350px;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 3px solid purple;
border-radius: 10px;
clear: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
float: right;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
width: 350px;
padding: 10px;
border: 3px solid purple;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
clear: right;
}

#rightcolumn2 {
float: right;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
width: 350px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
padding: 10px;
border: 3px solid purple;
border-radius: 10px;
clear: right;
}

footer {
position: fixed;
border: 1px solid purple;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
z-index: 50;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It is because of the order you have put the elements. put the first two right columns above the long left columns and you will see that gap covers

Comment: Thanks so much Joykal Infotech! I will add these findings to the original post in detail to further aid in any future incidents others may have. Have a great day!

Comment: I've moved the answer to a Community Wiki answer, feel free to edit further.

Comment: I've removed the live demo link, as this will likely be fixed based on the answer given, and thus will not show the problem as originally described. Questions need to be self-contained so they do not depend on links that can go stale. Please add any extra information into the question if required, so that any future reader can understand it based on the information contained therein. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author)*.

From the comment from *Joykal Infotech*:

> Solution: It is because of the order you have put the elements. put the first two right columns above the long left columns and you will see that gap covers.

I had my right column divs in order like any other page but for some reason pasting the right side divs in front of the left div allowed them to finally clear! If your divs are auto expanding (vertically) as mine are they sometimes need enough content for them to close the gap!